# Rust: Apply function n times

Tags: rust, functional-programming, borrow-checker

### The problem

I want to create a function (`chain`) that takes a function `f: Fn(i32) -> i32`, number `n` and returns a new function `g: Fn(i32) -> i32` that applys `f` to it's input `n` times.

For example: `chain(3, f)` should return a function eqvivalent to: `|x| f(f(f(x)))`.

Here is my attempt at achieving this (*similar code works in Python*):

```
fn chain(n: i32, f: Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>) -> Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    println!("This is not printed when the resulting function is called!");
    match n {
        1 => f,
        _ if n > 1 => {
            let g = chain(n - 1, f);
            Box::new(move |x| g(f(x)))
        },
        _ => Box::new(|x| x),
    }
}
```

The compiler produces some errors about borrowing moved values, and I can't figure out how to fix them.

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `f`
 --> src/lib.rs:7:22
  |
1 | fn chain(n: i32, f: Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>) -> Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> {
  |                  - move occurs because `f` has type `Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
6 |             let g = chain(n - 1, f);
  |                                  - value moved here
7 |             Box::new(move |x| g(f(x)))
  |                      ^^^^^^^^   - use occurs due to use in closure
  |                      |
  |                      value used here after move
```

### Background

I want to create a program that takes an arithmetic expression in string form and then creates a function that can evaluate the expression. For example: `"2*x+3"` should result in a function `|x| add(mul(2,x),3)`. The resulting function is called many times and should execute as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `f` twice. You cannot. You cannot use a reference either, since the function is local and you cannot return a reference to it.

The simplest fix is to replace `Box` with `Rc`:

```rust
fn chain(n: i32, f: Rc<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>) -> Rc<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    println!("This is not printed when the resulting function is called!");
    match n {
        1 => f,
        _ if n > 1 => {
            let g = chain(n - 1, Rc::clone(&f));
            Rc::new(move |x| g(f(x)))
        },
        _ => Rc::new(|x| x),
    }
}
```

However, this incurs an overhead of a dynamic function call for each operation, an I think a simple `match` to the operation will be faster.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do that is to implement it with iteration instead of recursion:

```
fn chain(n: i32, f: Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>) -> Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    println!("This is not printed when the resulting function is called!");
    Box::new (move |x| {
        let mut r = f (x);
        for _ in 1 .. n {
            r = f (r);
        }
        r
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=522ed594e0f2fbeb79e2be92ebf258d0)

For extra performance, this even allows you to get rid of the boxes and avoid the dynamic function calls:

```
fn chain(n: i32, f: impl Fn(i32) -> i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    println!("This is not printed when the resulting function is called!");
    move |x| {
        let mut r = f (x);
        for _ in 1 .. n {
            r = f (r);
        }
        r
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2bc635782800ea7c0442385944d290b)